# In Strongloops' Loopback, How to deny access to all methods except one?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have a model, which I want to have only one remote method, and I want to deny access to all other by default methods, and keep only remote one.
DENY For all users /Countries and /Countries/*
Allow For all users /Countries/status

Answer (score 3):

You can disable remote methods by calling disableRemoteMethod() on your model.

```
module.exports = function (Country) {
  var isStatic = true;
  var isNotStatic = false;

  Country.disableRemoteMethod('deleteById', isStatic);
  Country.disableRemoteMethod('create', isStatic);
  Country.disableRemoteMethod('upsert', isStatic);
  Country.disableRemoteMethod('updateAll', isStatic);
  Country.disableRemoteMethod('findById', isStatic);
  Country.disableRemoteMethod('exists', isStatic);
  // Add any other methods you with to hide.
  // Use false for methods on the prototype object.
  Country.disableRemoteMethod('updateAttributes', isNotStatic);
};
```

https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Exposing+models+over+REST#ExposingmodelsoverREST-HidingmethodsandRESTendpoints

Answer (score 3):

You can use `loopback-remote-routing`

1. `npm install loopback-remote-routing --save`
2. Add the `mixins` in your `model-config.json`

   `{
     "_meta": {
       "sources": [
         "loopback/common/models",
         "loopback/server/models",
         "../common/models",
         "./models"
       ],
       "mixins": [
         "loopback/common/mixins",
         "loopback/server/mixins",
         "../common/mixins",
         "./mixins",
         "../node_modules/loopback-remote-routing"
       ]
     }
     ... 
   }`
3. Define the `only` or `except` rule in your `common/models/mymodel.json`

   `{
     ...
     "acls": [],
     "methods": {},
     "mixins": {
       "RemoteRouting" : {
         "only": [ "myMethod1", "myMethod2", ]
       }
     }
   }`

Comment: Thanks for this, best way I've seen so far to de-clutter the explorer UI

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to deny access to all the rest endpoints. You can go with loopback's acl model.
Here's the hyperlink on how to use it: [How to use access controls on loopback's rest endpoints](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Controlling+data+access)

> You basically deny access to all the rest endpoints, then explicitly grant access to one method i.e "status".

Else if you want to hide the rest endpoints, then @duffn's answer is good to go.